# Intel Quick Sync Video対応CPUかどうか判断したい

Tags: c#

今使っているPCのCPUがQuick Sync Video（QSV)に対応しているかをコード上(C#)で判定したいです。

最初は、WMIのWin32_Processorから取得できるCPUの製造元(Intel製以外を除外),モデル番号(Sandy Bridge以前のCPUを除外),名前(Celeron,Pentium,Atom,Xeonを除外)による判別を目指しました。

しかし調べてみると、QSVが利用可能なアーキテクチャーのモデル番号が非連続かつ間にQSV非対応アーキテクチャーが存在したり、（Ex:Sandy Bridgeの42,45の間にWestmereの44が存在）
一部アーキテクチャーではCeleron等の除外しようとした中に、一部QSV対応するモデルがあったりなどの例外があることがわかりました。

結果、一部の例外CPU名を手打ちで書き込むという、ミスが起こり得るようなスマートではないコードになってしまいました。

何かスマートにこれらの判別を行える手段はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

端末がQSVに対応しているかどうかを判定するためにはCPUモデルだけではなく、グラフィックドライバーのバージョンも考慮する必要があります。Intel Media SDKをどうにかC#から参照するか、他のQSV対応アプリケーションをうまく利用して判定するのが良いのではないでしょうか。

なお一般論としてCPUの判定にはCPUIDが利用できます。WMIでは`ProcessorId`で一部の値が取得可能ですが、これだけでQSV周りのフィーチャーフラグが全て参照できるのかは分かりません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Intel Media SDKを使う方向で検討していきたいと思います。